# How will I convert characters? Or other solutions

Tags: windows, delphi, ime

I found out [(though my other question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137335/is-this-a-bug-windows-api) that my IME outputs [Hangul Compatibility Jamo (U+3130 – U+318F)](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hangul_compatibility_jamo.html) instead of regular [Hangul Jamo(U+1100 – U+11FF).](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/hangul_jamo.html)

So I tried asking a [question in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/158477/what-korean-ime-can-i-use-on-windowsxp-for-my-specific-needs) about other IMEs, no replies yet.

**Should I just convert it myself? What exactly does that entail? Is it too complicated? Any ideas on how to?** Any help would be appreciated.

Language: Delphi
OS: WinXP
IME: Korean Input System (IME 2002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you could not write an interesting experimental editor control with its own built in Unicode Compose feature. However, before you did that, you might look for a way to change the configuration of the IME.  This seems to be a really interesting corner-case you have to work with. I was already surprised about your other question - that Windows has the ability to handle Raw Input from keyboards.

I found that source code for something that says it is the Korean IME is available for Windows CE.  You might learn something by studying it, even though it is for Windows CE rather than XP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee491900.aspx

Comment: If you google you might even find the file kimeui.cpp source code out there on the wild wild interwebs -- although I think that strictly speaking, that's a violation of Microsoft's copyrights.

Comment: Ooooh. thank you for the info. I'll take a look at it when I get back to work. I appreciate the answer.